# r in front of a string with regular expressions

Tags: python-3.x, regex, string, escaping

I understand that r in front of a string will make any of the escaping characters from that string to be considered a string. But I have the following code line (from the book I'm using to learn Python) where the first \ was used to consider the first () as string.

But if you put r in front of the whole string, wouldn't it make the first \ be considered a string as well? If that's the case, why would you use an escape character for the purpose of escaping the first () if the first \ itself will be escaped by the r?

The code line:

```
phoneNumRegex = re.compile(r'(\(\d\d\d\)) (\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d)')
```

Comment: In this very specific example the raw string (the `r` prefix) makes no difference since `\d` is not a control character. `'\d'` and `r'\d'` behave exactly the same.

Comment: There are two levels of escaping here: backslashes in Python string literals, and backslashes in regular expressions. `r` "disables" the special meaning of backslashes in Python string literals, but not in regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with raw strings (the `r` prefix). The `\(` inside the regex is for the regex engine and it means "search for a literal `(` and don't create a capture group".

```py
import re

string = '(literal parens)'
print(re.search('(literal parens)', string).group())
```

which outputs

```
literal parens
```

compared to

```py
print(re.search('\(literal parens\)', string).group())
```

which matches the literal `(` and `)`

```
(literal parens)
```